# Xamarin Facebook client async/await failed

Tags: c#, facebook, asynchronous, xamarin

GetTaskAsync seems not working with async/await. When stepping over GetTaskAsync, it always goes to the end of function even it is in a try block.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An async method with an awaited async call will immediately return and then continue when the async call has finished. You can try add a breakpoint on the next line after the async call (and/or inside your catch block) and hit continue when the method has returned and the debugger will come back to your method and break as soon as the async call has finished.